Clion Docker toolchain with ssh
I am using CLion to develop a set of libraries in C++. We have a set of versions that are not compatible between each other, so instead of removing the latest versions from my computer and installing the old ones in order to fix a bug, I decided to use the Docker Toolchain of CLion.
I have had no problem so far. However, my last change was to add cmake FetchContent that points to an internal repo. My problem is: I cannot clone the repo on the container when setting up the project from CLion. There is no option to use my ssh keys on the configuration, however when I run the base container "standalone" (I mean, without CLion) I have no issues on cloning the repo..
Is there a way to solve this?

From a look at the documentation for this feature, it seems you can bind-mount directories from your system to the container. Wouldn't that be sufficient to make your SSH keys and/or agent available to the build container?

Yes! it in fact the problem when I mount the .ssh directory was that the owner of the keys was not the root user in the container.. I have to create a user into the container with the same uid as mine. Thanks!

Just mounting the .ssh folder as explained by @Botje works, the only consideration is that the current user in the container should have the same UID:GID as the owner of the .ssh folder.
My container was running a root user, and my uid/gid was 1000, so I could not use the ssh keys. To solve this, I have created a user in the image with the same uid/gid as mine.
